# SSRS Calculated Expression- Returning a "1" if field includes text value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a calculated expression SMART=IIf(Fields!AgreementName.Value="S.M.A.R.T. Housing,1,Nothing) that is displaying a 1 if the AgreementName field "S.M.A.R.T. Housing".  This works only if there is one value (S.M.A.R.T Housing) in that field.  However, the issue is that this field can have 2 - 3 agreements (e.g. Mueller Development (PUD), S.M.A.R.T. Housing) and for data like this example, the calculated expression displays a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Contains()` method like this...

```
=IIF(Fields!AgreementName.Value.Contains("S.M.A.R.T. Housing"), 1, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks for the expression. That worked for the projects that had two agreement names in the field.